# Где хранить парсеры в проекта на Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Под парсером подразумевается скрипт, который запускается сервером с помощью CRON по расписанию и делает какие-то сторонние запросы, например к API с помощью CURL.
Имеется ввиду в какую папку положить его было бы архитектурно правильно? View таким вещам не нужен вероятно. Надо ли задействовать модель и контроллер? (ведь может быть работа с БД)

Comment: положить в папку `cron` :)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ну в дефолтной структуре проекта такой папки нет на сколько я помню )))

Comment: да, поэтому создать и класть всё, что надо. ведь также в корне есть папка `migration`, есть `componets`, могут быть `messages` и `tests`. cron ничем не хуже.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ок, папка cron но тогда в файлах из неё можно писать запросы напрямую к БД без использования ORM фреймворка. По сути это получится обычный отдельный скрипт который с фреймворком никак не связан

Comment: Почему это? Видел в папке `web` есть `index.php`, в котором подключается фреймворк? Никто не мешает сделать подключение аналогично и в папке cron. Например взгляни в файл `yii` без расширения в корне проекта. в нем тоже есть все эти подключения, чтобы можно было из батника его запустить или запустить различные команды из консоли типа init, migrate или еще что там есть